# How to get a server identifier in Sql Server without using a CLR stored function?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to query Sql Server and get an ID that identifies the machine on which SQL Server is installed. An ID that works well also in some complex scenarios like failover clusters, or similar architectures.

I need this for license check, i bind my licence key to a ID, currently i am creting "my id" using a combination of database creation date and server name, anyway this is not very good, expecially because it is a Database ID, not a Server ID.

In the past I used to read the harddisk serial number with an extended stored procedure, but isn't it there (at least in sql server 2008) a simple way to get this id?

I don't want to use a CLR stored procedure.

Comment: "an ID that identifies the machine on which SQL Server is installed" - "In the past I used to read the harddisk serial number" - what did you do when a disk was replaced?

Comment: I was giving another key, but the webserver was doing it for me automatically, and I allowed up to 2 disk changes before giving an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> et an ID that identifies the machine on which SQL Server is installed. An ID that works well 
>   also in some complex scenarios like failover clusters, or similar architectures.

So waht do you want? Identify the MACHINE or identify the CLUSTER and handle enterprise senarios?

In general this is not poossible wthout extended stored procedures or CLR. Point. You rule out all approache, then there are none left. And the fact that you did read the hard disc number already implies that you are NOT prepared to handle larger installs. What do you read if there is no hard disc (as disc), but a LUN on a SAN? What do you do in case the hard disc is a hardware raid controller? the approach you took from the start was pretty much not working but you failed to see it because you dont deal with enterprise customers ;) Which also means you dont handle complex scenarios (clusters etc.) ;)

As gbn says, don't bother enterprise customers with childish copy protections, put a license agreement in place. In general enterprise software has few technical limitations to allow enterprises to provide good service without running through hoops to get anoether licensing key jsut for a lab install.

Comment: why enterprise customers? I have customers with 3 employees and customers with 2000 employees. Moreover I have resellers that sell mainly to the 3 employees kind of customers, and these guys are not 100% honest, so I need to have some protection from them. From your reply and gbn too it seems that SQL Server is used only in big corporate scenarios, it is not, and therefore one must adapt. Anyway I choose this as reply wince it contains the real reply "In general this is not poossible wthout extended stored procedures or CLR. Point."

Comment: No, but it means your approach is faulty. Make it a license file (identify customer with it). Check activations. Finished. No need to track installs.

Comment: I have 300+ installations, some of them on failover cluster, anyway the current system works and it is also really complex and full of features (it allows a marketing partner to obtain automatically temporary activation keys for a potential customer). I cannot change this, I was just wondering if there were a way to check the "unique installation ID" with some better solution. In the scenarios I faced up to now the "trick" worked, I'll start getting worried once it won't anymore. (by trick I mean the DB creation time)

Answer (score 1):

It's called a "licensing agreement"

I wouldn't want some app shutting down because it thinks it is running a different box.

If we have a DR fail over in a log shipping or mirroring setup, these are 2 seperate SQL server installs. And what kind of server runs a single hard disk anyway?

Other SO questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=software+licensing

Comment: I set up a quite complete mechanism, I allow my users to change the so called ID 2 times before they cannot change without my manual operation. And this works very fine, they download activation keys from a webserver, in this way I control all the isntallations, otherwise for sure there will be leaks. The reason I need some check is that I don't do only direct sales, so to control this I need to have some mechanism. About the harddrive it was just an API used 10 years ago, anyway the trick I currently use (basically using DB creation datetime) is a good one, you son't suggest another, right?

Comment: @user193655: DB creation time? Fails for log shipping and mirroring too.